# How can I apply certain validations to objects created at a specific time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following validation in my model:

```
validates :price, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }, :unless => :free?
```

How can I only apply this validation to objects created after the June 6, 2014?

The object has a `created_at` attribute that's formatted like so: `2014-06-19 17:44:27`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `lambda` in the unless/if option of the `validates`:

```
validates :price, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }, if: -> { self.created_at > Date.parse('2014-06-19').beginning_of_day }
```

Also, make sure that the TimeZone is properly handled.